# i can't install the ibm_db python package in my azure function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, db2

I'm trying to access a IBM DB2 instance from an azure function, but as soon as i add the ibm_db package to my requirement.txt and publish the function, when trying to install this package it gives me the error described below

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.8.6/bin/python3.8 /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpohdx5kca
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ygqaie_9/ibm-db_ae91bb58811d4da4a16cf48bfdca7e17
  Complete output (8 lines):
  Detected 64-bit Python
  Detected platform = linux, uname = x86_64
  Downloading https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/linuxx64_odbc_cli.tar.gz
   Downloading DSDriver from url =  https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/linuxx64_odbc_cli.tar.gz
  Pre-requisite check [gcc] : Passed

  No Python.h header file detected.
  Please install python-devel or python3-devel as instructed in "https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/blob/master/README.md#KnownIssues" and continue with the installation
```

The goal is to be capable to access DB2 regardless the language. I tried with node and .NET but they also have their own issues with this package (or i may have done something wrong)

Any idea how to to avoid this error?

Thanks!

The goal is to reach DB2 and run SQL statements but i didn't even have the chance to install a package that allowed me to do this.
I tried by change the language of my function to node and .NET but they have issues as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that several online sources which describe the installation procedure for the `ibm_db` module do not specify clearly enough that the `python3-dev` dependency is an OS package. Adding `python3-dev` to `requirements.txt` simply will not work.

`python3-dev` must be installed as an OS package. In Linux you can accomplish that with:

```
apt-get install --yes python3-dev
```

The particular issue with Azure Functions is that the default Azure Function image does not include the `python3-dev` package. The only way to get `ibm_db` working is to create an Azure Function using a custom Docker image so you can install the `python3-dev` and another dependency you will come across, namely `gcc`. A useful tutorial on this topic can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deploy-container?tabs=acr%2Cbash%2Cazure-cli&pivots=programming-language-python).

Also note the Python version you are using since the Azure Function runtime (current version as of this writing is 4.x) only supports `GA (Python 3.10, 3.9, 3.8, 3.7)`, [see this page for supported versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=v4&pivots=programming-language-python#languages).

Given the above, an example `Dockerfile` for the Azure Function runtime version 4.x and Python 3.10 would be:

```
# To enable ssh & remote debugging on app service change the base image to the one below
# FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.10-appservice
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.10

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --yes gcc \
    && apt-get install --yes python3-dev

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

# This last line and any additional Dockerfile content will depend on your function
COPY . /home/site/wwwroot
```

It is also recommended that you include the specific versions of Python packages that your application is using, so, at the time of this writing, an Azure Function `requirements.txt` file using the `ibm_db` driver would need to contain:

```
azure-functions==1.15.0
ibm-db==3.1.4
```

One final note for Mac users with an Apple silicon (M1, M2, etc.) processor - ensure that you run your terminal with Rosetta so that you can compile the Docker image for the `amd64` architecture to ensure it will run in Azure. To confirm that your terminal is running Rosetta, run the `arch` command. You should get `i386` as a response. Building an `amd64` Docker image would then be done with:

```
docker build --platform linux/amd64 --tag <YOUR_DOCKER_ID>/<YOUR_IMAGE_NAME> .
```